# XA transactions in Spring Batch

Tags: transactions, batch-processing, spring-batch, distributed-transactions, xa

I'm writing a number of batch jobs with Spring Batch which mostly do export/import from/to database.
The Spring Batch job repository database and target database(from/to which I'm read/write data) are located on different machines.

My question is should I use XA transactions in this configuration?

I wondering about the scenario when at some point of time link to the job repository db brakes, will it potentially corrupt the data? Like this:

1. Job started (write to job repository)
2. Read/process/write in target db within transaction
3. Link to job repository db brakes and job fails

And finally I have updated target db but job is failed so same data will be processed again upon the job restart.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch has the facility within it's reader/writers to disable the interim state saving (you set the property `saveState` to false).  this allows you to manage the state of the processing independently of Spring Batch JobRepository.

in your example, you would maintain a 'processed flag' on the read table and modify the select statement to a `select * from x where processed = false`.  this would make you less dependent on the state of the JobRepository.

have a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#process-indicator that explains it in more detail.

Comment: That would help, but the problem that I can't modify the read table structure.

Comment: so we're back to what the jobRepository was designed to do; keep state in the absence of another mechanism.  my recommendation would be to keep a linear, non-transactionl log of your state via a listener or such that could be used to reconcile should their be a failure on the JobRepository.  this would allow you to reconcile and proceed in the case of an extra-ordinary failure.